# Applying cell style over already styled cell that is two style on single cell

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi

I am using `Apache POI` to create excel from csv file.
I have one column in this csv which tells what style should be applied on this row.

It contain Multiple value like 
`Bold|Red|grey`

What i want is to - apply style to cell one by one e.g. 
First Bold, over Bold i want to make it RED and then highlight row with GREY.

What i am doing right now is - splitting string of this column, running for loop and applying all three one by one.

But problem is only last style I got into excel, so last style override other styles.

Is there any way to append style and not override?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Did you try JexcelAPI. Let me check for POI in meantime.

Comment: You'll need one style for bold, one for red, one for red+bold etc

Comment: You cannot apply two or more cell style on any single cell at a time. You should do the same as suggested by Gagravarr